# Random numbers generator CLT , problem with dependence on $n$

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I have a few exercises concerning Central Limit Theorem in which I stumble upon the same problem.

Here is one of them:

A random numbers generator generates numbers with exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. What should $\lambda$ be and how many numbers should we generate so that the arithmetic mean of those numbers is $1$ with accuracy 
$0,01$ and the probability of this event is at least $0,9.$

This is how I do it:

$X_i = k_i$ = the number generated in the $i$-th draw, $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

$EX_i = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $\sigma = \frac{1}{\lambda}$

Standarization $$Z_n = \frac{S_n - \frac{n}{\lambda}}{\sqrt{n} \frac{1}{\lambda}} = \frac{\lambda S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

We need to estimate the following:

$$P(|\frac{S_n}{n}-1|<0,01) = P(\sqrt{n}(-0,01 \lambda + \lambda -1) < Z_n < \sqrt{n}(0,01 \lambda + \lambda -1)) = \Phi(\sqrt{n}(1,01 \lambda  -1)) - \Phi(\sqrt{n}(-0,99 \lambda +1)) = 0,9$$

And I do not know how to find $n$ or $\lambda$.

Could you explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: At least when n is large, the sample should have a mean close to 1/lambda and you want this mean to be close to 1 with large probability. This strongly suggests to choose lambda = $___$ . Can you finish the question now?

Comment: So $\lambda = \frac{1}{n}?$. I'm sorry but I don't see why the sample has a mean close to $1/ \lambda$. All I know is that $1 / \lambda $ is the expected value of $X_i$

Comment: No, λ is not 1/n, not even closely. If you "don't see why the sample has a mean close to 1/λ", pondering the consequences of the law of large numbers might help.

Comment: The law of numbers says that a sequence of indpendent radnom variables tith identical distr. satisfy $\frac{S_n}{n} \to EX_1$ a.s. $\iff$ $E|X_n|< \infty$. This condition is satisfied for $\lambda \neq 0$. Now I know why the means tend to $1 / \lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_N$ be the RV representing the mean of samples of size $N$. This has mean $E(M_N)=1/\lambda$ and variance $\mbox{Var}(M_N)=(1/\lambda^2)/ N$.

As we want $E(M_N)=1/\lambda=1$ we need $\lambda=1$.

Now assume the required sample size is large so we can use the CLT to justify a normal approximation for the distribution of $M_N \sim N(1,1/N)$

Now the question is what is the smallest $N$ such that 
$$
\mbox{Pr}(|m_N-1|\le 0.01) \ge 0.9
$$
So we are asking for the smallest $N$ such that the absolute value of a Standard Normal RV is less than or equal $0.01\times \sqrt{N}$and noting that a two-sided critical value for a $90\%$ interval has $z_{crit}=\pm 1.645$. That is that $0.01 \sqrt N \ge \Phi^{-1}(0.95)=1.645$

Hence we require the smallest $N$ for which $\sqrt N\ge1.645/0.01$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see, I wrote the same inequality while trying to solve this problem. But then I ended up with a difference of values of $\Phi$, both depending on $n$. Could you tell me how you found $N\ge1.645/0.01$? I mean, could you add some more detailed calculations so that I can see where I make mistakes?